# Can we resurrect a deleted post so I can clear a notification in my inbox?

Tags: bug, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I have this notification in my inbox that I cannot get rid of:

[image: Permanent Notification]

When I click on that page, it brings me to the closed and hidden question I had from March asking about the cost of the War on Drugs. Here's a screenshot of the page I get since, if you go to that link not signed in as me, you get a 404 page missing error:

[image: Deleted Question]

I don't care that the question is closed. I just want to bring it back temporarily, so I can check that comment and have that notification go away. I understand this is a really petty and minor issue. If the community thinks I should just deal with this notification forever, I'll just get on with it. But, if there is some way to bring the question back temporarily so, I can clear this notification, it would be really appreciated. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get oddly unclearable notifications all the time. I believe that's what the "Mark all as read" button is for. Seems like once a month or so I find myself having to click on that.

Try it and see if that fixes your issue.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Problem cleared.